# Display Full Date in React Using Words in DatePicker

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I have a very simple problem. I wanted to display the full date words, something like Nov 22th 2020.
Right now, i can only display the Month and the Date

Pls check my codesandbox

[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-driscoll-kc81g?file=/src/App.jsx)

```
   <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <DatePicker
        error={false}
        helperText={null}
        autoOk
        fullWidth
        inputVariant="outlined"
        value={selectedDate}
        onChange={handleDateChange}
        variant="outlined"
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is add prop `format` to picker, according to your example, you need `format="MMM do yyyy"`. [Here](https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/format) you can find more options